# Oracle SQL: How do I concatenate results into one column (with delimiters) and also rename the column?

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I have the following table.

```
Column_1 | Column_2 | Column_3
1        | 2        | 3
4        | 5        | 6
```

How do I come up with following result? (Let's say my delimiter is a column)

```
Concatenated_Result | Column_3
1, 2                | 3
4, 5                | 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select column_1||', '||column_2 as "Concatenated_Result"
     , column_3
from   table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   select Column_1 || ',' || Column_2 as Concatenated_Result, Column_3   from YourTable;
```

This is how you can get the desired result.